# SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error, Line 1 Character 6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, syntax

In the IE developer (F12) console, I've managed to get my pages to run without errors; all but one!

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>    mypage.php, line 1 character 6

I am using IE9.  Whats it's problem?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/files/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#donateButton").click(function() {
        alert('hey');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="javascript:void();" id="donateButton">asdsadasd</a>
</body>
```

When I click on `#donateButton` an error is produced. However, when I change `javascript:void()` to `#` then no error occurs any more. Why?

Comment: It's about line 1 of one of your `<script>` blocks I guess.

Comment: okay, but then thats just: "$(document).ready(function () {"

Comment: My psychic powers still lack the ability of remote debugging (I definitely should get that service pack installed one day). Please trim your HTML and JS down to a few lines where the error still occurs and then put the code in your question. It must be something like a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> "WAIT... does IE9 not like `<a href="javascript:void();" id="donateButton">` ?? It seems thats the problem..?"
>   — [Comment by Chud37](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262911/ie-syntax-error-line-1-character-6/11263324#comment14807046_11263324)

Yes, **that** is the problem. [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) is an **operator**, **not a function**. Use `javascript:void 0` , `javascript:void(0)` or `#`. Even better, add [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to your function:

```
$('#donateButton').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: so what can I use instead? If i use #, then IE will move to the top of the page annoyingly.

Comment: @Chud37 Read the answer. `#` has to be used in conjunction with `preventDefault()`.

Comment: javascript:void(0) does not work for me, but javascript:void 0 does work.