# ev.preventDefault(); and HREFs

Tags: jquery, html

After having my last question [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262911/script1002-syntax-error-line-1-character-6), I have never see the preventDefault(); function before.

So my question is now then, What is the best method?  I made the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='files/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#abc").click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            alert('hey');
            });
        });
       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>helloasdasdasdsad</h1>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <a href="javascript:void();" id="abc">Link 1: javascript:void();</a><BR><BR>
    <a href="#" id="abc">Link 2: #</a><BR><BR>
    <a href="javascipt:void(0);" id="abc">Link 3: javascript:void(0);</a><BR><BR>
    <a id="abc">Link 4: NO HREF</a><BR><BR>
</body>
</html>
```

..I hate using # because it scrolls to the top of the page.  It turns out javascript:void(); in the href will cause a syntax error in IE.  So is the answer to put the (ev) and `ev.preventDefault();` lines in **every** function? Or can I just `return false;` at the end of every function?

What is the best, most widely accepted practice?

EDIT:
Alright, so event.preventDefault(); is the best thing to use, But that still doesnt answer what goes in the HREF if i want a redundant link?  I thought best practice was to **always** use `.click` events with `<a href="">`, as some older browsers won't respond to a click event or hover on DIV/SPAN/IMG elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<a> script links without href="#"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144653/a-script-links-without-href)

Comment: shoot, that wasn't the right question, although very similar...there are other dupes around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) which should answer your question. Also, you don't need anything in hrefs.

Comment: so the answer is I simply leave the HREFs as "" and use preventDefault(); ??

Comment: The thing with missing of the `href` is that it can cause the anchor to not have various anchor properties in some browsers (eg no `:hover`, `:active` states, won't use pointer cursor etc) - you may as well use a span if you're not having any graceful degradation by using `href` for non-js users.

Comment: ...I thought it wasn't good practice to use `$("#foo").click` on anything that wasn't an `<a href="">` because of old browser use etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the anchors you don't want the click to do anything, add the preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

If your links are having only an empty `href="#"`, maybe you should consider you using a `<span>` or a `<div>` instead. This way you don't need the `e.preventDefault()` at all.

`e.preventDefault()` and `return false` both prevent the default event behavior. `return false` also prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM.

Using `href="javascript:void();` should be avoided if you want [unobtrusive code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Also ensure that you don't use the same id several places, as you do with "ABC"

Comment: yes the multiple #abc was purley because of laziness for the example.  But the question still stands then, what goes in the HREF?